# Rispondere ad una risposta a degli auguri? "Auguri." -> "Grazie, anche a te." ->?

Tags: word-choice, phrase-request

"*Auguri!*" -> "*Grazie, anche a te.*" -> **?**

Che frase usereste voi?

Vorrei ringraziare, ma per farlo un "*grazie*" semplice mi sembra riduttivo. Sarei tentato di rispondere "grazie, anche a te", ma non posso per perché ho fatto gli auguri per primo.

C'è un modo di rispondere che mi permetta di rispondere in maniera più elegante di un "*prego, grazie*"?

Una screen di Whatsapp qua sotto. Si tratta di conversazioni diverse per cui la mia prima frase per è sempre un "*Auguri!*" secco.

[image: Screen di Whatsapp]

Comment: "Grazie" va benissimo, normalmente nemmeno ci si arriva a questa terza frase/fase che ti preoccupa.

Comment: Ho aggiornato con un po' di casi

Comment: Se sono più persone, puoi dire "grazie a tutti". O forse sono io che non capisco.

Comment: Non trovo molto chiaro l'esempio con WhatsApp, anche perché non si capisce bene quante persone partecipano alla conversazione e perché non aggiunge molto alla domanda originaria.

Comment: Non vedo motivo per cui continuare a ringraziare e, no, non è un segno di maleducazione se è quello che vuoi sapere.

Comment: @karoshi si tratta di conversazioni diverse :P

Comment: @beppe9000 allora continua ad essere valido quanto già detto: puoi o ringraziare ogni persona individualmente, o semplicemente non dire nulla.

Comment: @DaG Ho voluto utilizzare WhatsApp per fare un esempio di vita real, e sopratutto perché mi sono posto la domanda che ho postato proprio osservando quella schermata.

Comment: @black quindi tu dici di non rispondere proprio, oppure solo che il non ringraziare non è maleducato? Nel secondo caso come risponderesti?

Comment: @karoshi il discorso è che un ringraziare e basta mi sembra troppo semplice

Comment: Non è maleducato non rispondere, anzi è la regola. Hai già fatto la tua parte facendo gli auguri per primo.

Comment: @karoshi Se inserisci questa cosa come risposta, la accetterò una volta che anche gli altri avranno risposto nei commenti.

Comment: La domanda di per se è ovviamente on-topic, però fa riferimento a una fattispecie che non si verifica, infatti il tutto è culminato in una digressione sul se sia maleducato o meno rispondere o non rispondere ad una risposta a degli auguri. Se c'è una risposta a questa domanda, per me andrebbe semplicemente ricercata nel primo commento, ovvero un "Grazie" andrebbe benissimo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normalmente, quando ci si scambiano gli auguri, il dialogo segue una struttura simile alla seguente:

> A: Auguri!
>
> B: Grazie, anche a te  (o: anche a te e famiglia, o similari)

Non c'è bisogno che la persona che ha iniziato il dialogo aggiunga altro; in fin dei conti, ha fatto gli auguri per prima, come la si può accusare di maleducazione? Ha già fatto la sua parte.

Se proprio si vuole rispondere, non si può sbagliare con un semplice "grazie":

> A: Auguri!
>
> B: Grazie, anche a te
>
> A: Grazie.

Ma ripeto, la terza frase non è obbligatoria, e si può evitare tranquillamente senza rischiare di passare per maleducati.